# apply two nested sub-totals to a table in Excel 2007

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I would like to apply two nested sub-totals to a table in Excel 2007, but I find that the "SubTotal" button does not seem to work consistently.

Imagine the following table

```
Year    Colour  Amount
2011    Red     10
2011    Green   20
```

If I select all the rows and click on "SubTotal" with the following parameters

- At each change in - **Year**
- Use Function - **Sum**
- Add subtotal to - **Amount**
- Replace current subtotals - **No**
- Page break between groups - **No**
- Summary below data - **No**

I then do exactly the same but
- At each change in - **Colour**

I get the following nice table which is exactly what I want

```
Year    Colour  Amount
Grand Total     30
2011 Total      30
    Red Total   10
2011    Red     10
    Green Total 20
2011    Green   20
```

Imagine though that I change "Green" to "Red" in the original table

```
Year    Colour  Amount
2011    Red     10
2011    Red     20
```

If I follow the above steps, then I would expect to see the table looking in the same format. However I get the following

```
Year    Colour  Amount
    Red Total   30
Grand Total     30
2011 Total      30
2011    Red     10
2011    Red     20
```

As you can see the Red Total is at the top whereas I would like it to be after the row "2011 Total" just as it is in the first table.

Is there any way of working around this. [I know I can do this manually, but would like to use the SubTotal button]

To summarize, I need both the 2011 and the Colour to be sub-totaled, but in a way that first the 2011 is sub-totaled, and then the Colour (as in the first table I show above). This needs to work whatever the data that makes up the table. For me, it only works with the first data set, but not the second data set.

**QUESTION UPDATED**

Here is an example. The example includes an extra ten "Price" columns not mentioned in the problem. The reason why I have shown these ten columns is to show why PivotTables are not my ideal solution. I did not think it is possible with PivotTables to show the "details" of the rows inline with the subtotals - in the manner depicted in the picture.

[image]

Comment: You should learn how to use PivotTable reports. They do exactly what you need

Comment: Thanks d--b.  PivotTables are definitely an option. However what I omitted from the question was that there are another 10 columns which I want to display. Admittedly the Pivottable would allow me to see these columns via "Show Details" however I ideally wanted 1. the ability to see the details inside the actual report itself 2. to do this for multiple drill-downs- something which I think is difficult with Pivottables

Comment: That's a good point. But at least now I know that I probably have to write code for it and if I ever write the code I can post it here!

Answer (score 2):

I agree with d--b - you are going to want to use pivot tables - they provide alot more intuitive features(in my opinion) than the subtotal system does:

[image: PivotTableExplanation]

The subtotal system is dependent on the initial sorting and organization of the data for what it produces. Whereas pivot tables do not care whether/how your initial data is sorted.

Good Luck.

**EDIT:**

You can still manipulate the subtotal table using standard copy/cut and paste features - it will maintain its tree structure:

[image: SubtotalSolution1]
[image: SubtotalSolution2]
[image: SubtotalSolution3]
[image: SubtotalSolution4]

So basically feel free to move the rows around using cut and paste however you want it to look - you can even move individual cells around within a row - it will still maintain it's structure/look. Good Luck.

Comment: PivotTables are definitely an option. However what I omitted from the question was that there are another 10 columns which I want to display. Admittedly the Pivottable would allow me to see these columns via "Show Details" however I ideally wanted 1. the ability to see the details inside the actual report itself 2. to do this for multiple drill-downs- something which I think is difficult with Pivottables

Comment: I don't see how the number of columns you have would effect anything. The subtotal function is not going to combine those columns for you in any way either. If you want to combine them in some way you are going to have to do that before you use the subtotal or pivot table features. I'm not sure how "show details" relates to anything either. So basically I think you should provide an axample of what you are trying to achieve with those ten other columns.

Comment: if this _[I know I can do this manually, but would like to use the SubTotal button]_ is not that necessary, Stepan1010 displayed the way, I've tried too - I can't think of anything else - anyone?!

Comment: I assumed by not wanting to do it "manual" he meant manually creating sum cells. The ability to cut and paste in the subtotal feature without losing structure seems to me to be an intentional design choice of the subtotal feature to me. So I think it is the exact solution he is looking for - I think.

Comment: Hi Stepan1010. Thanks for your screenshots... I have tested out your thesis - that cutting and pasting in subtotal doesn't lose the structure... It seems to me that tweaking would still be needed - for instance sometimes needing a group outline. (I have been testing on my workbook which actually has five nested subtotals.) I would anyway still need to write a macro to cut and paste the rows, so I would probably be better off writing a macro to do the subtotals exactly as I want... Although I will probably just go down the PivotTable path...

Answer (score 0):

Try to play with *Replace current subtotals - **YES***

Had a bit to play around until i could reconstruct your problem, but this solved it.

It worked, when I had your example reconstructed, then marked the whole thing and did subtotal again, with replacement of current subtotals.

It worked also when I did your example on a *clean* pure data table.

And to reconstruct your example I had to use subtotal without replace on a subtotaled table grouped by color.

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Hi Jook! Did you manage to keep the subtotaling by year AND the subtotaling by colour. If I understand correctly, the replace current subtotals - YES option on colour simply removes the subtotals for year.

Comment: No, I did not. I didn't catch this point that explicit until your comment - maybe you should edit your question a bit. But, now that I know that, I can confirm your trouble. I think this could be even a bug sortof of subtotal, because it needs a different color in order to do the grouping right. Now I am interested too, if there is any other way, than to code a custom subtotal :)

Comment: Hi Jook. I have hopefully made the question much clearer! Thank you.